# UiApp.getActiveApplication.remove(0) doesnt work when I'm not signed in

Tags: google-apps-script

I have published the script as webapp and in the setting I have selected run the script as me and it can be accessed by anyone.

however, I find that if I'm not logged in, then the app doesn't get removed. In my script everytime the value in a listbox change, the content of the current app will be removed and widget readded. If I'm not signed in, the content of the current app stays, so I will have what was in the app and the new content embedded below it.

Please help me, how do I get the app.remove(0) working even when I'm not signed in?

Thanks,

Comment: You can delete  your question if you don't need an answer...unless you consider it might be usefull to others, in which case it would be nice to explain how you solved your problem by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add mainPanel.clear () before
UiApp.getActiveApplication.remove (0)

this ensures the app is removed even when im not signed in. i think its probably gas quirk or something.  cos i dont need clear when im signed in.